# is layer0 and layer-1 blockchain both mainnet?

Tags: blockchain, layer-2

I want to ask here a fundamental question about the difference between layer 0 and layer 1 for my understanding. i have read you can create main blockchains on layer 1 which lacks scaling. while the layer 2 are mostly side chains facilitating layer 1. while layer 0 are also main blockchains facilitating scalability and interoperability .

1. layer 1 is the main blockchain
2. layer 0 is also the main blockchain
3. layer 2 are sidechains

My question is that layer 0 and layer 1 will be called main blockchains?

my second question is that while initially creating blockchain the first question we must decide is that on which layer our blockchain will be layer 0 or layer 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer 0 methods, or network layer methods, are where the mechanism to improve interoperability and scalability operate at the network level of the blockchain architecture stack.

Layer 1 methods are also called on-chain methods, are where the blockchain protocol itself is enhanced to improve scalability. This layer represents the blockchain itself.

Therefore, Layer 1 is the main blockchain.

Yes, while initially creating blockchain the first question we must decide is that on which layer our blockchain will be layer 0 or layer 1. If your blockchain wants to improve interoperability and scalability at the network level, you can create a layer 0 blockchain. If your blockchain wants to improve scalability at the on-chain level, you can create a layer 1 blockchain.

Comment: furthur elaborating , i would mention an analogy here,to clear my understanding i would say layer 0 is c++ providing bare metal infrastructure and layer 1 is c# where you have link list and lists already there?  am i right

Comment: If you want to mention an analogy in programming languages, I would compare layer 0 to be an array or linked list data structure, and layer 1 to be the stack and queue class that’s implemented using the array or linked list data structure. Layer 2 would be an program or application that’s implemented using the stack or queue data structure (that itself is implemented using array or linked list).